Solving interaction between glossaries-extra and fancyhdr
I'm writing a PhD thesis in Spanish using LaTeX, and I have encountered an unexpected issue. I tried to add the chapter title in the header (using fancyhdr) in lowercase. I also have some sections that are not directly chapters (such as the list of tables or the bibliography) but should be treated the same way, so I used \nouppercase to achieve this.
The problem arises with the bibliography ('bibliografía' in Spanish). For some reason, when I apply this methodology, the accented letter 'i' appears in uppercase (BibliografÍa). I was confused, so I simplified the document and discovered that this problem disappears when I remove the glossaries-extra package.
This example document demonstrates the issue I mentioned; when glossaries-extra is removed, the problem magically disappears.
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum} % Para generar texto de ejemplo
\usepackage[backend=biber,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage[toc,nomain,nonumberlist,acronym]{glossaries-extra}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\makeglossaries

\setlength{\headheight}{13pt}

\fancypagestyle{fancy}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[LE]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
    \fancyhead[RO]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}             % Center the page number in the footer
}
\pagestyle{fancy}

% Definir una versión en minúsculas del título de la bibliografía
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\bibtitle}{\MakeLowercase{\bibname}}
\makeatother

% Añadir referencias directamente en el documento
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{smith2020,
        author    = {John Smith},
        title     = {Research in Esclerosis Múltiple},
        year      = {2020},
        publisher = {Scientific Press}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
    
    \tableofcontents
    
    \printglossaries
    
    \chapter{Introducción}
    \lipsum[1-5]
    
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography[title={Bibliografía}, heading=bibintoc]
    
    \clearpage
    \lipsum[6-10]
    
\end{document}


I'm not really sure how could I proceed right now, so does anyone have an idea about how to solve it? Thanks in advance.

Welcome to TeX.SE! Did you get error messages or warnings? Please show the first error message!

Hi, thanks @Mensch! The truth is that, after a couple minor changes to remove unrelated messages, I don't see any error or warning in the example that I provided. It seems that, from the log file point of view, everything is working fine.

When I run your example, I get a normal lowercase accented  'Bibliografía' (copied from the PDF file). So maybe your TeX system should be updated.

Thanks @PietervanOostrum, you were right. I was running LaTeX in Ubuntu using TeX Live from APT, and it seems that this way is not completely up-to-date. After installing the vanilla version from TUG (https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html), this problem seems to be solved.
